# iText and Spring MVC - Create report from objects list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, itext

I need to create a report (PDF file) with a list of objects from my controller class. I'm using Spring MVC and the method is as follow:

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publicationsPDF")
public List<Publication> publicationsList(Model model){
    List<Publication> publications = publicationService.publicationsList();
    model.addAttribute("publications", publications);
    return publications;
}
```

But I don't know how to get all those objects into my table.

```
public class PublicationsPDF extends AbstractPdfView{

@Override
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
        Document document, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // Here I need to get all those objects placed in my controller class and then list them in table.

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    tabla.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
    tabla.setWidths(new float[] {1.0f, 3.0f, 6.0f});
    tabla.setSpacingBefore(10);

    PdfPCell column = new PdfPCell();
    columna.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    columna.setPadding(3);

    columna.setPhrase(new Phrase("ID"));
    tabla.addCell(column);

    columna.setPhrase(new Phrase("Title"));
    tabla.addCell(column);

    columna.setPhrase(new Phrase("Content"));
    tabla.addCell(column);

    document.add(table);

    }
}
```

What I need to do in order to get a report with all those objects? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Google?  http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x

Comment: The objects don't actually come from your controller class, they come from the publicationService. Why not just add the publication service reference to your PublicationsPDF class? Or better, have the buildPdfDocument take in a list of publications and have your controller pass that in.

Comment: @SteveHall thanks for info... Now I'm working over it.

Comment: @hofan41I need to work with the controller because later I will set up authorizations over each methods (@PreAuthorize annotation). Thanks by the suggestion.